# Javascript ajax call uncaught reference error

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Hi i have an php application,but my javascript causing an errors it runs perfectly on localhost but when i upload into amazon elasticbeanstalk it show me this errors `Uncaught ReferenceError: getEvent is not defined`  This are my code:

index.phtml

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../public/js/page/home.js"></script>
$(document).ready(function(){
getEvent();
});
```

home.js

```
function getEvent()
{
    var count=1;
    $.ajax({
        url:baseUrl + "event/popularevent",
        data:{'count':count},
        dataType:"json",
        type:"POST",
        async:false,
        success:function(data){
            var eventHtml = '';
            eventHtml = '<li class="clearfix media-block module-li">' +
                    '<div class="media-avatar-passport">' +
                        '<div class="photo-box pb-60s">' +
        '<a class="event-photo" href="/events/san-francisco-halloween-beer-olympics-halloween-drinking-games-1-beer-free">' +
            '<img class="photo-img" alt="Photo of HALLOWEEN BEER OLYMPICS! Halloween Drinking Games + $1 Beer!  FREE!" height="60" src="#" width="60"></a></div>' +

        '</div><div class="media-story">' +
                '<div class="item-title clearfix">' +
        '<a href="/events/san-francisco-halloween-beer-olympics-halloween-drinking-games-1-beer-free" class="url summary">HALLOWEEN BEER OLYMPICS! Halloween Drinking Games + $1 Beer! &nbsp;FREE!</a></div>'+

        '<div class="item-description">'+
        '<span class="extra">'+
        '   Tomorrow, Oct 26, 8:30 pm'+
        '</span><p class="fine-print">140 are interested</p></div>'+
        '</div></li>';
            //alert('ok');
            $('#popular-events .module-list').html(eventHtml);
        }
    });
}
```

Where i made a mistakes, the problem it runs without error on localhost not on deployment server.Thanks

Comment: have you checked the permissions for your ajax-url?

Comment: how is that..? it works on localhost..

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell without seeing the environment but I would guess that one of two things is going on.

either home.js was uploaded to the wrong location or its file permissions are set incorrectly

Comment: but i have other function too request in similar manner but it works..?

Comment: hmm, so you have a call to another function in home.js that is working?  Did you recently add getEvent() to home.js? Maybe its just a cache issue.